# Split input of apply function using a continuous classifier

Tags: r, plyr, apply, reshape

I have the example data frame

```
test.df<-data.frame(classifier=runif(n=1000), x1=rnorm(1000), x2=rnorm(1000), x3=rnorm(1000))
```

with `x1`,`x2`,...,`x10000`

I would like to use the `apply` function to perform a large amount of tests (lets say `t.test`) and collect the results in a vector(lets say `t.test()$p.value` ). The test on a single column would be `t.test(test.df$x1[ test.df$classifier<0.4 ], test.df$x1[ test.df$classifier>0.6 ])$p.value`

I would like to perform this on all with `x1`,`x2`,...,`x10000`. I though I would use the `apply` function with `MARGIN=2` but I cannot get the `apply` function to split every column vector according to the `classifier`.

(The example provided above has absolutely no statistical meaning. Don't go viral)

Any help?

Comment: Is it a `t.test` or is that also just an example?

Comment: My original function is a custom function but its `arguments` are like the `t.test`. For the example you can use the `t.test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
df<-data.frame(classifier=runif(n=1000), x1=rnorm(1000), x2=rnorm(1000), x3=rnorm(1000))
sapply(df[,-1], function(v) {
  t.test(v[df$classifier<0.4], v[df$classifier>0.6])$p.value
})
```

Which gives :

```
       x1        x2        x3 
0.5028683 0.1238735 0.2021623
```

Comment: Yes. That's it. Why did you choose `sapply` over `apply`. Just out of curiosity is it possible to perform the same using `apply`?

Comment: @ECII, `sapply` because data.frame is internally a list and it is straightforward to pass columns with `sapply`. check my answer for how to use `apply`, although `sapply` is what you should use.

Comment: @juba, (+1), but I suspect `sapply(2:ncol(df), function(idx) t.test(df[[idx]][df[[1]] < 0.4], df[[idx]][df[[1]] > 0.6])$p.value)` would be faster (if the OP doesn't want the names).

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply`:

```
idx <- matrix(2:ncol(test.df), ncol=1)
apply(idx, 1, function(x) {   
    v1 <- test.df[test.df$classifier < 0.4, x]
    v2 <- test.df[test.df$classifier > 0.6, x]
    t.test(v1, v2)$p.value
})
```